# How to escape html code?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, themes

WordPress says, "You always want to escape when you echo, not before." Now how to escape below line in my plugin. Notice that I pass a variable inside html.

```
$wfam_woocommerce_active = '<th>Woocommerce</th>';
echo '
<div class="wfam-restrict-individual-file_list-wrapper">
    <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list users">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image Name</th>
                ' . $wfam_woocommerce_active . '
                <th>Access Type</th>
                <th>User Roles</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping depends on two things: what your variable contains, and what its container is. What the variable contains means - is it a URL? A string? JS? and so forth. What its container means - is it an attribute? Is it enclosed between two HTML tags? and so forth.

Assuming your variable `$wfam_woocommerce_active` is a string that does not contain HTML, and also that you probably want it output inside of a `<th></th>` tag, for this instance you could use:

```
<th>' . esc_html( $wfam_woocommerce_active ) . '</th>
```

If instead the variable contains the `<th></th>` tags, you could use

```
' . wp_kses_post( $wfam_woocommerce_active ) . '
```

which means to allow only the HTML that is allowed in Posts, which includes `<th></th>` and many other tags.

See more about [escaping in the developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/).